# Why does re-search-backward give different result in python-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have been using python-mode for a long time. And I always use subword-mode. But subword-mode behave strangely in python-mode. For example, the `M-b` movement. If there is a variable named `test_varialbe` and I put the cursor at the end of this variable, in python-mode `M-b` will make the cursor point to `t` while in other modes it will go to `v`.

So I looked into the source of subword-mode and found the following function:

```
(defun subword-backward-internal ()
  (if (save-excursion
        (let ((case-fold-search nil))
          (re-search-backward
           (concat
            "\\(\\(\\W\\|[[:lower:][:digit:]]\\)\\([[:upper:]]+\\W*\\)"
            "\\|\\W\\w+\\)")
           nil t)))
      (goto-char
       (cond
        ((and (match-end 3)
              (< 1 (- (match-end 3) (match-beginning 3)))
              (not (eq (point) (match-end 3))))
         (1- (match-end 3)))
        (t
         (1+ (match-beginning 0)))))
    (backward-word 1)))
```

After making some tests, I found `re-search-backward` is giving different result in different modes. If I `eval-expression` the `(let ...)` expression in python-mode, the cursor will jump to the space before `test_varialbe`, and in other modes it will jump to `-`.

Why is this? What has caused `re-search-backward` to behave differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that there are differences in the Syntax table definition of '_'.

In Python mode '_' has a syntax definition of "word" whereas in other cases it is defined as "symbol". Look at [Elisp manual: Syntax tables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html)

Comment: Indeed, and the official opinion of the Emacs maintainers is that it's a bug for a major-mode to behave this way (only actual letters need to have "word" syntax, other punctuation chars that can be part of identifiers should have "symbol" syntax).

Answer (score 0):

in addition:

Grasping identifiers, basic commands like `forward-word' make more sense with "_" on word syntax. AFAIK Emacs doesn't provide the respective commands WRT with symbols.