# Why does haskell mode step on s-lower-camel-case and how does it do it?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have prepared a minimal working example to check that other dependancies have not interfered with this. The test function is:

```
(defun test-haskell-problems ()
    (interactive)
      (insert (s-lower-camel-case "other_string")))
```

And a full reproduction of the problem (with package installation) occurs with this:

```
(setq package-list '(
                     s
                     haskell-mode
                     ))

(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
    (require 'package)
      (package-initialize)
        (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
          )

; activate all the packages (in particular autoloads)
(package-initialize)

; fetch the list of packages available 
(when (not package-archive-contents)
    (package-refresh-contents))

; install the missing packages
 (dolist (package package-list)
   (when (not (package-installed-p package))
     (package-install package)))

(require 's)
(defun test-haskell-problems ()
    (interactive)
      (insert (s-lower-camel-case "other_string")))
```

By activating this function `test-haskell-problems` in a haskell buffer we get the string result `other_string` expected result and result in `*scratch*` buffer is `otherString` I don't understand what's happening here?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Probably the same reason explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13354655/319698).

Comment: That is exactly the problem, instead of messing with word definitions, it would be best if you were to do you camel casing inside a temp buffer and then insert it's contents. `(insert (with-temp-buffer (s-lower-camel-case "asdf_asdf")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the syntax entry that defines what a "word" is. In Haskell, asdf_asdf is one word and s.el does camelcasing by splitting a string by words.

An easy solution would be to perform your camel casing in a temporary buffer.

```lisp
(insert (with-temp-buffer (s-lower-camel-case "asdf_asdf")))
```

A more correct solution would be to temporarily redefine the word boundaries.

EDIT: here it is

```
(insert (with-syntax-table (make-syntax-table) (s-lower-camel-case "asdf_asdf")))
```

This is also much faster:

```lisp
(benchmark 10000 '(with-temp-buffer (s-lower-camel-case "asdf_asdf")))
"Elapsed time: 1.188508s (0.204679s in 2 GCs)"

(benchmark 10000 '(with-syntax-table (make-syntax-table) (s-lower-camel-case "asdf_asdf")))
"Elapsed time: 0.368366s (0.191607s in 2 GCs)"
```